# Averaging Filter using python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I am new in python and trying apply averaging filter on image as the way i understand averaging concept

> summing up the neighboring elements including itself and divide it by number of elements
>   [technique](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MH5cc.gif)

But the problem is getting dark image rather then blur image as result

```
image = cv2.imread('./images/hip-salt.jpg', 0);
width = image.shape[1]
height = image.shape[0]
result = np.zeros((image.shape[0], image.shape[1]), int)

def meanFilter():
  for row in range(height):
     for col in range(width):  
         currentElement=0; left=0; right=0; top=0; bottom=0; topLeft=0; 
         topRight=0; bottomLeft=0; bottomRight=0;
         counter = 1           
         currentElement = image[row][col]

         if not col-1 < 0:
             left = image[row][col-1]
             counter +=1                        
         if not col+1 > width-1:
             right = image[row][col+1]
             counter +=1 
         if not row-1 < 0:
             top = image[row-1][col]
             counter +=1 
         if not row+1 > height-1:
             bottom = image[row+1][col]
             counter +=1 

         if not row-1 < 0 and not col-1 < 0:
             topLeft = image[row-1][col-1]
             counter +=1 
         if not row-1 < 0 and not col+1 > width-1:
             topRight = image[row-1][col+1]
             counter +=1 
         if not row+1 > height-1 and not col-1 < 0:
             bottomLeft = image[row+1][col-1]
             counter +=1 
         if not row+1 > height-1 and not col+1 > width-1:
             bottomRight = image[row+1][col+1]
             counter +=1

         total = int(currentElement)+int(left)+int(right)+int(top)+int(bottom)+int(topLeft)+int(topRight)+int(bottomLeft)+int(bottomRight)
         avg = total/counter
         result[row][col] = avg

meanFilter(); 
cv2.imshow('Averaging Filter', result);
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: one thing to note is that if you are using python 2 then `total/counter` will return a truncated int

Comment: using python 3 and i actually making a gui appliction using pyqt for image processing

Comment: Can't you use cv2/numpy functions instead of reinventing the wheel?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I tested your code and the issue appears to be the type!

the values of result are `int` but they should be `uint8`
you can either fill it in correctly to begin with or recast it before displaying, like this:

```
result = result.astype('uint8')
```

why are you making this filter manually though? why not use the built in blur filter? you may want to read [this](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/d13/tutorial_py_filtering.html)

Comment: result = np.zeros((image.shape[0], image.shape[1]), np.int8)

changing this lines gave a better result, not totaly dark image but also not desired image (blurred image)

Comment: result = np.zeros((image.shape[0], image.shape[1]), dtype='uint8') it should be