# Averaging filter in image processing

Tags: python, image-processing, average, opencv

I need a program that blurs an image, using averaging filter. It also must work with different sizes: 3x3, 5x5, etc.

Here is what I have:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

image = cv2.imread('tranquility.jpg')

#blur = cv2.blur(image,(3,3))
width = image.shape[1]
height = image.shape[0]
result = np.zeros((image.shape[0], image.shape[1]), dtype='uint8')


def meanFilter():
    for row in range(height):
        for col in range(width):
            currentElement = 0;
            left = 0;
            right = 0;
            top = 0;
            bottom = 0;
            topLeft = 0;
            topRight = 0;
            bottomLeft = 0;
            bottomRight = 0;
            counter = 1
            currentElement = image[row][col]

            if not col - 1 < 0:
                left = image[row][col - 1]
                counter += 1
            if not col + 1 > width - 1:
                right = image[row][col + 1]
                counter += 1
            if not row - 1 < 0:
                top = image[row - 1][col]
                counter += 1
            if not row + 1 > height - 1:
                bottom = image[row + 1][col]
                counter += 1

            if not row - 1 < 0 and not col - 1 < 0:
                topLeft = image[row - 1][col - 1]
                counter += 1
            if not row - 1 < 0 and not col + 1 > width - 1:
                topRight = image[row - 1][col + 1]
                counter += 1
            if not row + 1 > height - 1 and not col - 1 < 0:
                bottomLeft = image[row + 1][col - 1]
                counter += 1
            if not row + 1 > height - 1 and not col + 1 > width - 1:
                bottomRight = image[row + 1][col + 1]
                counter += 1

            total = int(currentElement) + int(left) + int(right) + int(top) + int(bottom) + int(topLeft) + int(
                topRight) + int(bottomLeft) + int(bottomRight)
            avg = total / counter
            result[row][col] = avg


plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(image),plt.title('Original')
plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(result),plt.title('Blurred')
plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

For some reason the original image is blue, though, it should have normal skin colour. In addition, Blurred version is plain purple colour. How can I modify the code so it blurs my image normally.

Additional info:

1. I was referring to this topic: [Averaging Filter using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49553590/averaging-filter-using-python);
2. Using an averaging filter code from here, does, actually, blur an image, but it's blue for some reason. [OpenCV](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_filtering/py_filtering.html)

Update: [Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1Ja2.png)

Comment: As stated in the post you mention, coding a filter that already exists is not the correct way to do! Better use `scipy.ndimage` library or similar ones. The true question is why your image is blue. This could be an issue with the data type of your image. Check if `image` values are between 0 and 255 for example

Comment: Please show your **actual**, original image - a screen-grab of it composited with another is not very easy for us to experiment with!

Comment: Updated with original image

Comment: No, you have not. Your code loads a JPG image and you have supplied a PNG image as your original. Please make sure your code and your image correspond exactly to what you tested.

Comment: You define a function `meanFilter` but never call it. This is the reason that your output image is all zeros (in the color map that pyplot uses by default to show gray-value images, zero is mapped to publish blue).

Answer (score 2):

Your original image looks blueish because `cv2.imread` returns an image with 3 channels in this order: blue, green and red. `plt.imshow` works with RGB images, so you need to convert the original data:

```py
bgr_image = cv2.imread(your_image_filename)
rgb_image = cv2.cvtColor(bgr_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
plt.imshow(rgb_image)
```

As stated by Romain, you would be better of using a library instead of coding your filter. In your particular case, `cv2.blur` does exactly what you are looking for:

```py
# 3x3 mask
blurred_image3 = cv2.blur(bgr_image, (3, 3))
cv2.imwrite('blurred_image3.png', blurred_image3)

# 5x5 mask
blurred_image5 = cv2.blur(bgr_image, (5, 5))
cv2.imwrite('blurred_image5.png', blurred_image5)
```

The result image for mask 3x3:

[image: blurred image, mask 3x3]

The result image for mask 5x5:

[image: blurred image, mask 5x5]

Comment: Thanks! I think it's my fault I haven't stated that the assignment requires an averaging filter to be written manually, without using "blur"